# Laravel Eloquent Relationship issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three models - Blog,Post,Comment.
Blog has many Post
Post has many Comment

when I write

```
return Blog::with('posts','posts.comments')->get();
```

It will give all the blogs with posts and comments.
But how I will get those blogs which are created by admin user i.e. user_id which is in comments table. Where to write `->where` condition.

```
return Blog::with('posts','posts.comments')->where('comments.user_id','=','23')->get();
```

gives error.

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "comments"
LINE 1: select * from "blogs" where "comments"."is_...
^ (SQL: select * from "blogs" where "comments"."user_id" = 23)
```

How to solve this issue.

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: Side note: you only have to do `posts.comments` and not both since nested relationships will load every relation it iterates through (`posts` & `comments`)

Comment: Your question isn't making a lot of sense.  You want blogs which are created by a certain user but the user_id is in the comments table.  Why or how would the writers of the comments for a blog dictate who the blog itself belongs to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, You wan to get all the posts that have been commented by a specific user.

From what you have done so far,`whereHas()` might be what you are looking for. This is how you could do it.

```
return Blog::with('posts.comments')
                ->whereHas('posts.comments', function($q) use ($user){
                  $q->where('comments.user_id', $user->id);
              })->get();
```

source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
return Blog::with([ 'posts', 'posts.comments' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('comments.user_id', '23');
}])->get();
```