# How to change the regular query to laravel query (laravel 5)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My regular query is like this :

```
SELECT a.nationality_id, a.nationality_name, b.province_name, c.city_name
FROM tb_general_nationality a
JOIN tb_search_province b ON a.nationality_id = b.country_id
JOIN tb_search_city c ON b.province_id = c.province_id
WHERE b.country_id = 50
```

I change the query to laravel query like this :

Service :

```
public function listCity($param=null) 
    {
        $city = City::with('province','country')->where('tb_search_province.country_id',$param)->get();        
        echo json_encode($city);        
    }
```

Model :

City Model :

```
namespace App\Models\City;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class City extends Model {

    protected $connection = 'pgsql';        

    protected $table = 'tb_search_city';

    public function province()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Province\Province','province_id','province_id');
    }                  

}
```

Country Model :

```
namespace App\Models\Country;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model {

    protected $connection = 'pgsql';        

    protected $table = 'tb_general_nationality';

}
```

Province Model :

```
namespace App\Models\Province;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Province extends Model {

        protected $connection = 'pgsql';        

        protected $table = 'tb_search_province';

        public function country()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Country\Country','nationality_id','country_id');
        }      

    }
```

But, my laravel query not working. 
There exist error. The error is like this :

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "tb_search_province"
LINE 1: select * from "tb_search_city" where "tb_search_province"."c...
^ (SQL: select * from "tb_search_city" where "tb_search_province"."country_id" = 50)
```

My Table is like this:

```
tb_search_city (city_id, province_id, city_name)
tb_search_province (province_id, country_id, province_name)
tb_general_nationality (nationality_id, nationality_name)
```

How to change the regular query to laravel query?

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm not certain this would cause the issue, but I believe your [`belongsTo`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) should be `$this->belongsTo('App\Models\Country', etc...` with only one `Country`.

Comment: Also, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29754408/laravel-eloquent-relationship-issue) might be helpful.

Comment: In the with function you must type province.country because it's a nested relationship.